# NodeJS - Vulnerable lab

Tags: node.js

Found this which works as expected:
https://github.com/JavanXD/nodejs-backend-vulnerable-to-sql-injection

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

you code sample is incomplete, but i think this is the line throwing.

```
if (err) throw err;
```

if you dont catch this throw then the app will crash.
hence, to solve your problem, remove this line, or catch the error

Comment: Thanks for your comments Raphael. the line "throw err" just provides an informative error to the console, regardless of the crash itself. without using this line, the stack trace isn't informative at all - https://prnt.sc/1qkniw8. as well - about the code, sure. here is the full code if it's needed - https://pastebin.com/XAgYtpcy